# Apache RewriteRule with Proxy and Changing Content-Type

Tags: mod-rewrite, httpd, mod-proxy

We are currently using mod_proxy to proxy to proxy to the correct destination with the following line:

ProxyPass /my-path balancer://server/path/to/real/thing

However, a third party is sending us requests with the wrong content type.  Getting them to change is not an option, so I thought that using mod_rewrite I would be able to do this with the following

RewriteRule ^/my-path(.*) balancer://server/path/to/real/thing$1 [P,T=text/xml]

However, this does not seem to be doing anything, and the rule does not appear to be being executed.

Is it possible to use mod_rewrite to achieve this, and am I setting this correctly for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If your rule is not being executed then it may best to use the rewrite log to debug, details here: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteLog

Post the log if you are having trouble interpreting it.

However You should be able to use the Header directive to do this. mod_rewrite should always be the last resort.